# Google share explicit load

Tags: google-plus, share

Idea:
After dynamic content is loaded, on mouseover I'm trying to render google share button like it says on the official google developer's site.

Code I'm using is:

```
gapi.plus.render(div);
```

Facts:

- If I change plus to plusone, it renders google plus button instead share. ( Means: Scripts load up )
- If I remove {"parsetags": "explicit"}, Buttons load up ( But doesn't load up on hover )

Problem: 
**Share button doesn't load up.**

Debuging links with plus.render and plusone.render:

1. http://romanlosev.igloro.info/googleshare.php?load=plusone ( plusone - works, but plus+ buttons load up )
2. http://romanlosev.igloro.info/googleshare.php?load=plus ( plus - doesn't works )

Answer (score 7):

There's a similar question [on StackOverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680969/how-to-load-google-plus-share-button-in-iframe/13573282#13573282).

What you need to do is call the explicit render method for the share buttons.  Replacing your function that selects the div with the following code will delay render for the share objects on screen.

```
$("#clickme").click(function()
{
  gapi.plus.go();
});
```

To render individual buttons, you must pass an object with the action parameter set to share, for example:

```
gapi.plus.render("plusOne", {action: "share"});
```

The following is a more complete example, that does asynchronous script loading and renders various share targets, visible [here](http://wheresgus.com/incrender.html):

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>
  <div data-action="share" class="g-plus" id="plusOne"></div>
  <button onClick="gapi.plus.render('plusOne', getParamBag('https://www.google.com'))"></button>
  </p>
  <p>
  <div data-action="share" class="g-plus" id="plusTwo"></div>
  <button onClick="gapi.plus.render('plusTwo', getParamBag('https://plus.google.com'))">  </button>
  </p>
  <p>
  <div data-action="share" class="g-plus" id="plusThree"></div>
  <button onClick="gapi.plus.render('plusThree', getParamBag('https://developers.google.com'))"></button>
  </p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.___gcfg = {
      lang: 'en-US',
      parsetags: 'explicit'
  };
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
  function getParamBag(url){
    return {
      action: "share",
      href: url
    };
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: It will render all objects. But i dont need to render all objects. After load content, objects count will increase and "gapi.plus.go()" will load very long and will lag.

Comment: In the case use gapi.plus.render(div) but like Gus shows in his example trigger that at the correct time whether that is a click or after loading dynamic content. You will need to retain the parsetags: explicit setting too.